# Pandas: Series of quotients of adjacent elements

Tags: pandas

For a Series `x`, `x.diff()` creates a new Series `y` with `y[0] == NaN`, `y[1] == x[1] - x[0]`, `y[2] == x[2] - x[1]`, etc. Suppose I want the equivalent with division rather than subtraction, such that `y[1] == x[1] / x[0]`, etc. What's a good way to compute that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a combination of `shift` and `div` function for `pandas.Series` like below:

```
In[1]: import pandas as pd

In[2]: import numpy as np

In[3]: series = pd.Series(np.arange(5) + 1)

In[4]: series.div(series.shift(1))
Out[4]: 
0         NaN
1    2.000000
2    1.500000
3    1.333333
4    1.250000
dtype: float64
```

[pandas div](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.div.html)

[pandas shift](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html)

Comment: This one is probably more efficient than mine (no apply).

Answer (score 2):

With the following series:

```
ser = pd.Series(np.random.randn(5))

ser
Out[65]: 
0    1.206456
1   -0.209808
2   -0.200228
3    0.657034
4    1.395551
dtype: float64
```

You can use [rolling().apply()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rolling.html) (pandas 0.18.0+):

```
ser.rolling(2).apply(lambda x: x[1] / x[0])
Out[66]: 
0         NaN
1   -0.173904
2    0.954342
3   -3.281423
4    2.124018
dtype: float64
```

Or, [pd.rolling_apply()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.rolling_apply.html) (for earlier versions):

```
pd.rolling_apply(ser, 2, lambda x: x[1] / x[0])
Out[67]: 
0         NaN
1   -0.173904
2    0.954342
3   -3.281423
4    2.124018
dtype: float64
```